# Where can I find beta users?

Tags: beta, beta-testing

I was wondering where can I find beta users for my website? Are there websites that help you find beta users?

Comment: Post a URL, I'm sure people will be happy to visit it and check out if it is worth using.

Comment: Once your site is out of beta, where will you find your users? That's probably where you should look for beta users.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest just submitting the site to places like Digg and Stumbleupon.  You'll get a more people viewing your site, where you can offer beta testing as an option.

Answer (score 3):

That's all too dependent on what sort of crowd your site targets.

Try to find a forum related to the subject and post there, and if it's general-purpose, you could try out a general forum like Something Awful.

In addition, you could create a [Twitter](http://twitter.com) account for the site and have your friends [retweet](http://kevinrose.com/blogg/2009/1/21/what-is-rt-retweeting.html) a beta invitation; that's a quick way to get it touch with a lot of people if your site is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply invite your friends to try it and tell you what they think. Social networks may be helpful.